# Cannot reach a value on the object data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In variable called 'data' I have this data:

```
{"user":"peter","expires":1601630467}
```

I am trying to reach `"expires"` so I've done this:

```
console.log(`data expires value: ${data.['expires']}`);
```

But the above returns undefined even though when I do:

```
console.log(data); I get {"user":"peter","expires":1601630467}
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Either use dot notation `data.expires` or the bracket notation `data['expires']`. Don't mix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either write

```
console.log(`data expires value: ${data['expires']}`);
```

or

```
console.log(`data expires value: ${data.expires}`);
```

as an object property can either be accessed `this['way']` or `this.way`.

Comment: that's what I did in the first one...when I try data.expires I get error: Property 'expires' does not exist on type string

Comment: Then assuming that `data = {"user":"peter","expires":1601630467}` I can only guess that you've made some other mistake around.

Comment: @user13962846 Then you are probably dealing with JSON. See the duplicate question on how to handle that.